# How to read symfony fetched data from database

Tags: symfony

I am very new to symfony and got knowledge in php. On my project my end result of db query is $user.\

if i use print_r($user) i get this result

```
xxx\xxxx\Article Object ( [username:xxxx\xxxx\Article:private] => asdfasdf [passsword:xxxx\xxxx\Article:private] => [usertype:xxxx\xxxx\Article:private] => gaeafsdfa)
```

how can i fetch the username to check against a specific user and if condition passes change password to other.

All i need to how to read the username and  how to set the password.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

I got to call as

```
$user->getUsername(); // to see the user name
$user->setPassword($generatedPassword); // to update the password.
```